Dynamic Variable assignment from table of tables
I’m trying to make dynamic variables, based on the names of columns of the tables of some data sets.
This is my Code:
varnammes = ["SpeedGoatT" "imu1_accel_x" "imu1_accel_y" "imu1_accel_z"  "imu1_gyro_x"   "imu1_gyro_y"   "imu1_gyro_z"   "imu1_orient_i" "imu1_orient_j" "imu1_orient_k" "imu1_orient_r" "imu2_accel_x"  "imu2_accel_y"  "imu2_accel_z"  "imu2_gyro_x"   "imu2_gyro_y"   "imu2_gyro_z"   "imu2_orient_i" "imu2_orient_j" "imu2_orient_k" "imu2_orient_r" "imu3_accel_x"  "imu3_accel_y"  "imu3_accel_z"  "imu3_gyro_x"   "imu3_gyro_y"   "imu3_gyro_z"   "imu3_orient_i" "imu3_orient_j" "imu3_orient_k" "imu3_orient_r" "imu4_accel_x"  "imu4_accel_y"  "imu4_accel_z"  "imu4_gyro_x"   "imu4_gyro_y"   "imu4_gyro_z"   "imu4_orient_i" "imu4_orient_j" "imu4_orient_k" "imu4_orient_r" "imu5_accel_x"  "imu5_accel_y"  "imu5_accel_z"  "imu5_gyro_x"   "imu5_gyro_y"   "imu5_gyro_z"   "imu5_orient_i" "imu5_orient_j" "imu5_orient_k" "imu5_orient_r" "imu6_accel_x"  "imu6_accel_y"  "imu6_accel_z"  "imu6_gyro_x"   "imu6_gyro_y"   "imu6_gyro_z"   "imu6_orient_i" "imu6_orient_j" "imu6_orient_k" "imu6_orient_r" "imu7_accel_x"  "imu7_accel_y"  "imu7_accel_z"  "imu7_gyro_x"   "imu7_gyro_y"   "imu7_gyro_z"   "imu7_orient_i" "imu7_orient_j" "imu7_orient_k" "imu7_orient_r"];
Tables = struct();
for i = 1:length(files)
    load(files(i))
    varName = sprintf('Table0%d', i-1); % Create a variable name
    Tables.(varName) = logsout.FileLogSignals{4}.Values;% Set the variable in the structure
    Tables.(varName) = timeseries2timetable(Tables.(varName));
    Tables.(varName) = timetable2table(Tables.(varName));
    Tables.(varName) = splitvars(Tables.(varName), 2);
    Tables.(varName).Properties.VariableNames(2:end) = varnammes;
    for x = 1:length(varnammes)
    % this is the problem:
    varName = [char(varnammes(x)) num2str(i-1)];
    eval([varName ' = x^2;']);
    %
    end
end

This is a test version that is making the variables, I want but instead of making them x^2, I want them to be the column that goes with the variable.
The normal code would be something like:
imu1_accel_x = Tables.Table00{:,3};

or:
imu1_accel_x = Tables.Table00.imu1_accel_x;

making the output being imu1_accel_x0, with all the values of column imu1_accel_x.
I tried making the eval line:
eval([varName ' = Tables.Table00.imu1_accel_x;']);

But I got an error and don't know why or how to make it work as intended.

What benefit are you hoping to reap by creating loads of dynamic variable names? It's generally a bad idea for a few reasons (performance, debugging, syntax checking, ...). You could just make more table columns - you've already shown how to use dynamic column names?

Please see this answer for reasons not to use dynamic variable names, and good alternatives to them.
